# Stop script when condition is first satisfied

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that checks whether cells within range A10:A160 are not empty, and if not empty, then ranges B5, B6, B7 must also not be empty, otherwise unique message boxes generate with instructions and the user cannot save the workbook. The issue is that the message boxes generate each time the condition is met for each non-empty cell it encounters in A10:A160. I would like for each unique message box to pop up only on the first occurrence of the true condition set for each message box.

For example:

- A10:A15 are not empty.
- B5, B6 are empty.
- Message box should appear only once with instruction for B5.
- Message box should appear only once with instruction for B6.

Below is a snippet of my code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range, r4 As Range
        Set r1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A10:A160")
        Set r2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")
        Set r3 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B6")
        Set r4 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B7")
    For Each cell In r1
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) And IsEmpty(r2) Then
        Application.Goto r2
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Number is Required in order to Save. Save Cancelled!"
    End If
    Next
    For Each cell In r1
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) And IsEmpty(r3) Then
        Application.Goto r3
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Name is Required in order to Save. Save Cancelled!"
    End If
    Next
    For Each cell In r1
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) And IsEmpty(r4) Then
        Application.Goto r4
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Division is Required in order to Save. Save Cancelled!"
    End If
End Sub
```

I think the line "For Each cell In r1" is causing the script to run for each non-empty cell in A10:A160 but the script requires a "For" prompt. I've read through many stacks but am not sure what the "For" logic should be. I also tried using "Exit For" but that stopped the script entirely.

Answer (score 1):

A bit simpler:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rngInfo As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    If Application.CountA(ws.Range("A10:A160")) > 0 Then  'any data?
        rngInfo = ws.Range("B5:B7")
        If Application.CountA(rngInfo) < rngInfo.Cells.Count Then
            'list all required fields
            MsgBox "Entries for Number, Name and Division are all Required in order to Save. Save Cancelled!"
            Application.Goto rngInfo(1)
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the response! I'm getting a runtime error and it is pointing me to the line, 'rngInfo = ws.Range("B5:B7")'. The error is "Object variable or With block variable not set." To answer your question, yes range A10:A160 could be any data, letters or numbers. Also, the note to "list all required fields", is that just a description of the MsgBox prompt or are you indicating that I need to list the range B5:B7 there?

Comment: I figured it out! It did need the "Exit For" prompt, I simply did not have it in the correct order. My revised code: 'For Each cell In r1
If Not IsEmpty(cell) And IsEmpty(r2) Then
Application.Goto r2
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Project Number is Required in order to Save. Save Cancelled!"
Exit For
End If
Next'   Thank you again for your help! Being able to talk about and see alternatives allowed me to zero-in on the issue!